# Чем отличается outline от margin?

Tags: html, css

Если margin - это внешний отступ, то что делает outline  в отличии от margin?

Comment: Как можно сравнить outline, с margin? Margin — это пространство, разрыв, outline — это узор в виде границ.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline#try_it

Comment: Чем отличается краска от рамы? Если рама - это внешняя для стекла конструкция, то что делает краска в отличии от рамы?